# Prestashop pagination weird behaviour of previous button

Tags: javascript, php, pagination, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

im working on building shop with Presta,
I have problem with previous button in pagination at category page, it always adds something to href, it wouldn't be a problem but i wrote javascript to operate things like changing products per page or category filters by changing links.

Lets say my actual link is something like

> localhost/index.php?id_category=10&controller=category?resultsPerPage=18&page=2

Normally previous button should have href to

> localhost/index.php?id_category=10&controller=category?resultsPerPage=18

But in my case it has href to

> localhost/index.php?id_category=10&controller=category?resultsPerPage=18y

I tried to make js script to slice last letter from href, but it just doesnt work, there's always something added to this href, letter isn't problem it just looks weird but site as far as i tested works fine, but if it is digit it can result in change properties of for example resultsPerPage. I wonder if its a problem with Pagination.php and its' link building method, because in my scripts i have nothing that could couse this problem, maybe anyone had same problem and knows any solution?

Comment: None of those URLs make much sense to begin with, because they all contain a second question mark, that should actually be an ampersand.

Comment: @CBroe, its just because im currently working with friendly urls off. 
If i turn friendly urls on it looks like: 

Current url: http://localhost/10-cattegory_name?resultsPerPage=18&page=2
What previous button should have: http://localhost/10-cattegory_name?resultsPerPage=18
What it have: http://localhost/10-cattegory_name?resultsPerPage=188, 

As you can see, clicking previous button now results in changing resultsPerPage to 188, instead of acctualy going back to first page of result page with only 18 products.